# Difference between WebDriver and Selenium in Selenium Grid Node Configuration

Tags: webdriver, selenium2

I'm using Selenium Grid and noticed that I can configure the seleniumProtocol parameter for the different capabilities in the Node. I can chose between *WebDriver* and *Selenium*.

**Excerpt from my node.json**

```
{
  "capabilities":
  [
    {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "platform": "WINDOWS",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    },
    {
      "browserName": "firefox",
      "platform": "WINDOWS",
      "maxInstances": 205
      "seleniumProtocol": "Selenium",
      "firefox_binary"=".\\firefox-22\\firefox.exe"
    }
  ]
}
```

**What are the differences between those two options?**

I couldn't jet find any relevant notes in the internet or the selenium grid wiki.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Selenium Grid and Node is downward compatible. It works with Selenium 1 and Selenium 2 / WebDriver.

The `seleniumProtocol` parameters define for what version of Selenium the configuration apply.

- `Selenium` = Selenium 1
- `WebDriver` = Selenium 2 / WebDriver